# DokuWiki: Include content from Django Application

Tags: django, dokuwiki

The "intranet knowledge base" of the company I work for is our DokuWiki.

I want to add some data to dokuwiki of a django application.

I found the dokuwiki plugin [include](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:include), but this seems to be only able to include wiki pages, not external resources (via https://....).

How can I add content from a web application to dokuwiki?

Support for authentication (dokuwiki needs a password to access the web application) would be good.

Comment: It's 100% ok if you down-vote my question. But please leave a comment why you do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an iframe, with the [iframe plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:iframe).

Note that the other application needs authentication of its own.
But it is applied then on that included page also, depending if you are logged into the browser. Displaying authenticated pages on behalf of this wiki is an other question, needs more complex approach.

Comment: Just found the [scrape plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:scrape), which is capable to grab part of given external page and include it on a wiki page. Seems working, and this can be even more useful than an iframe, but it sure not works with authentication, which is trivial with the iframe.

Comment: To do authentication on behalf of the user from the server code is really an other question. It can be implemented though, easier if the application and dokuwiki uses the same, common authentication backend, and harder if not. I'm not aware of any plugin doing this.